# Resample() function in R's terra package and the r.resamp.interp module in GRASS GIS yield such different rasters

Tags: raster, grass-gis, interpolation, resampling, terra

Comparing the results from the `resample()` function in R's `terra` package (version 1.7-29), and the `r.resamp.interp` GRASS GIS module (version 8.2), I find differences in how they apply bilinear interpolation. The differences are large!

Using `terra`:

```
library(geodata)
library(terra)

# get elevation for Madagascar
elev <- elevation_30s('MDG', path=getwd())

# crop to make this all faster
w <- 49.13
e <- 50.39
s <- -16.37
n <- -15.06
extent <- ext(c(w, e, s, n))
elev <- crop(elev, extent)
```

GRASS likes to report extents and resolutions in degrees-minutes-second format for unprojected coordinate systems, so to make this easier, I'm going to project the raster to an equal-are projection.

```
library(enmSdmX)
CRS <- getCRS('Madagascar Albers')
elev <- project(elev, CRS)
```

Now, resample to a coarser resolution:

```
template <- aggregate(elev, 4)
terra <- resample(elev, template, method='bilinear')
```

In GRASS called using `rgrass` in R:

```
library(rgrass)

# connect to GRASS (first argument is where GRASS is installed on my Windows system)
initGRASS('C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 8.2', home=tempdir(), SG=elev, location='default', mapset='PERMANENT')

# export SpatRaster to GRASS
write_RAST(elev, 'elev')

# reshape GRASS region to match the template raster's resolution and extent
extent <- ext(template)
extent <- as.vector(extent)
w <- as.character(extent[1])
e <- as.character(extent[2])
s <- as.character(extent[3])
n <- as.character(extent[4])

rows <- nrow(template)
cols <- ncol(template)

execGRASS('g.region', rows=rows, cols=cols, n=n, s=s, e=e, w=w)

# resample
execGRASS('r.resamp.interp', input='elev', output='grass', method='bilinear')

# return to R
grass <- read_RAST('grass')
```

So these should be the same, correct?

```
terra

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 41, 38, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 3633.887, 3633.887  (x, y)
extent      : 687969, 826056.7, 1074146, 1223136  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Tananarive (Paris) / Laborde Grid 
source(s)   : memory
name        : MDG_elv_msk 
min value   :    7.294359 
max value   : 1115.549438

grass

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 41, 38, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 3633.887, 3633.887  (x, y)
extent      : 687969, 826056.7, 1074146, 1223136  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=labrd +lat_0=-18.9 +lon_0=44.1 +azi=18.9 +k=0.9995 +x_0=400000 +y_0=800000 +ellps=intl +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs 
source      : file688441b57662.grd 
name        : file688441b57662 
min value   :         6.128405 
max value   :      1138.687195
```

Note the big differences in min/max values.

```
delta <- terra - grass

plot(delta)
```

[image: Differences between terra and GRASS]
Such big differences!

Differences seem biased slightly high at low values and biased low at high values:

```
combo <- c(terra, grass, delta)
combo <- as.data.frame(combo)
names(combo) <- c('terra', 'grass', 'delta')
plot(combo$terra, combo$delta)
```

[image: Plot of deltas by value in raster resampled in terra]

A bit of the difference lies in the fact that GRASS drops some cells that `terra` does not. From the GRASS manual page for `r.resamp.interp`: "Note that for bilinear, bicubic and lanczos interpolation, cells of the output raster that cannot be bounded by the appropriate number of input cell centers are set to NULL (NULL propagation). This could occur due to the input cells being outside the current region, being NULL or MASKed."

But the cells GRASS drops are not responsible for most of the differences (red is cells dropped by GRASS but not be `terra`):

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(elev, main='Original')

plot(terra, col='red', legend=FALSE)
plot(grass, col='yellow', legend=FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

[image: Left: Original raster. Right: Cells dropped by GRASS]

There are several ways to do bilinear interpolation; I'd assume they'd be equivalent, with allowances for rounding error since some are approximations.  However, the differences I get between `terra` and GRASS are much bigger than is reasonable to expect for rounding approximation.

Why do `terra` and GRASS yield such different rasters when using what is presumably the same interpolation method?

Edit #1: Mistakenly said I was using a different DEM than the one I actually am. Corrected type in title.

Comment: Perhaps the difference is due to the change to coarser resolution with `aggregate` in R before resampling?

Comment: On your suggestion, I used `r.samp.stats` to aggregate the raster in GRASS to the target resolution, then resampled to the (same) resolution. The largest differences were still up to +/-~90. That's less than the largest differences I got above, but still big.

Comment: Can you make the GRASS output available?

Comment: Sure! Here are the outputs from terra::resample() and GRASS's r.resamp.interp module.  Note that GRASS trims the raster so it has no row/columns with all NAs, so you'll have to extend it to match the one from terra. Thanks for taking a look! https://github.com/adamlilith/stackoverflow_questions/tree/main/terra_vs_grass_resample